Meaning of 春天一到，花園裡綠意盎然
春天一到，花園裡綠意盎然
In general, this sentence means when spring comes, the garden is vigorous/blossoming with greenery or something like that.
My question is what does 意 mean? I've looked online and some websites say it's "scenery", but this definition does not exist with the word 意 by itself. Thank you.

《漢語大詞典》：意，意味，情趣。南朝梁江淹《臥疾怨別長史》詩：「始懷未及嘆，春意秋方驚。」金元好問《王黃華墨竹》詩：「亦有文湖州，畫意不畫形。」《元史·巎巎傳》：「善真行草書，識者謂得晉人筆意。」馬南鄒《燕山夜話·三分詩七分讀》：「如果沒有什麼詩意，就連三分詩也不像了。

只有春意盎然，没有绿意盎然这个说法。

意 implies 意境 (artistic mood)
綠意 = a mood created by the green (plants) = a green scenery - sceneries create moods. (imagine a field of grass and trees all around you)
Similarly:
春意 = a mood created by the spring = a spring scenery (imagine flowers start to bloom)
秋意 = a mood created by the autumn = a fall scenery (imagine falling red leaves)

春天一到，花園裡綠意盎然


Once Spring arrives, the green scenery is exuberant in the garden

Notice:
"色" means "color"  and  "秋色" (color of Autumn) means "color of Autumn" which implies "Autumn scenery". Although the character 色 itself doesn't contain the meaning of scenery, it is used as a shorthand for 景色(scenery). Just as 意 doesn't contain the meaning of mood, it is used as a shorthand for 意境 (mood)
More study:
In 寒意 (feeling of chill), 意 is short for 意識 (awareness = feel)
In 殺意 (murderous intention), 意 means "intention" - one of the meanings of this character

基本解释
意味yìwèi
(1) [meaning;significance;implication]∶含蓄的意思
意味深长的一笑
(2) [interest;overtone;flavor]∶情调;兴趣;趣味
这首诗意味无穷
诗歌之意味。——蔡元培《图画》
绿意盎然的意是什么意思?
What is the meaning of 意 in 绿意盎然?
绿意盎然中的“意”意味着“意味”。
The "意" in 绿意盎然 means “意味”.
“绿意盎然”是一个汉语词汇，
“绿意盎然”is a Chinese phrase.
其含义是“鲜花盛开，春意盎然”。
which means "fresh flowers blooming, everything is lush green".
在这个成语中，“意”指的是“意味”，
In this phrase, “意”refers to “意味”
而“盎然”则表示一种洋溢、深厚的状态。
and “盎然”expresses a kind of deep, brim-full state.
因此，  “
Therefore,
“绿意盎然”
用来形容春天的意味非常浓烈，
is used to describe a very strong sense of springtime,
表达了春天生机勃勃、万物复苏的美好景象。
expressing the vitality of springtime, with everything restored to a beautiful state.
这个成语可以用作谓语、定语或状语，用于描写春天的景色，
This saying can be used as a predicate, attributive or adverb,
用于描写春天的景色，
(can be) used to describe springtime scenery,
是一个中性成语。
(it) is a neutral phrase
例如，可以说“三月的北京，春意盎然”，
For example, (we) can say, "(In) Beijing in March, the flavour/sense of spring abounds."
来形容春天北京的生机勃勃和美好。
to describe springtime Beijing as full of vitality and beauty. (vis-à-vis the natural environment at least.)
